# Web Deploy connection timed out

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy, webdeploy-3.5

I've previously had Web Deploy up and running without any issues. Following a company wide installation of Bitdefender, Web Deploy has stopped working. I've tried the following without any success

Added the following rule to Bitdefender firewall

- Local Address: Any
- Remote Address: our server IP port 8172
- Protocol: TCP
- Direction: Both
- IP: Any
- Network: Home / Office
- Permission: Allow

Using the following telnet command, **telnet [IP address] 8172**, I get a blank screen.

Navigating to the URL for the publishing server connection, I'm prompted with a login and then a blank screen.

I don't have Fiddler, or anything similar, running.

I've tried on other machines in our office yet I get the same response.

Re-installed Web Deploy via Web Platform Installer Recommended Server Configuration for Web Hosting Providers and using command prompt I've restarted the agent services with the following commands

**net stop msdepsvc** & **net start msdepsvc**

**net stop wmsvc** & **net start wmsvc**

I've added IIS Manager Permissions to the appropriate site in IIS, using the server administrator account (which worked in the past) and configured web deploy publishing.

I'm running out of ideas of what to try so I'd appreciate any suggestions.

When attempting to validate the connection in Visual Studio I see the failed notification, "The operation has timed out".

Comment: I am experiencing this exact issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Nick I'm still to find a fix for this.

Comment: what happened? I thought that worked for you?

Comment: @Nick Still experiencing issues deploying from a local to a remote environment after BitDefender was installed. Our build server is on a different network, which doesn't have BitDefender, so we use that for our deployments without any issues. Hoping to find a solution for the local environment issues one day.

Comment: Ok, why did you accept/unaccept the answer? I may have been able to help, but I no longer have access to that environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Policies for Content Control. Exceptions need to be added for the sites you would like to web deploy to.

Click on policies, then go to the policy that applies to your development system. In my case this was "IT Policy." If you don't know, you can go to Network and drill down through Active Directory to find what policy applies.

[image]

Next, go to Content Control => Traffic. Check the boxes for Web (HTTP traffic) and Traffic Scan exclusions. Then add the URL or IP address for whatever system you are trying to deploy to (We used IP).

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Thanks for your help